# Допускают ли коллекции дублирование?

Tags: java, коллекции

Почему в книге "Хорстманн К. - Java. Библиотека профессионала, том 1" написано, что коллекция не допускает дублирование объектов? Это касается любой коллекции которая реализует интерфейс Collection? Или какой-то определённой реализации? Я специально привёл цитату всего раздела 9.1.2., даже из контекста непонятно что имеется ввиду.

> 9 .1.2. Интерфейс Collection Основополагающим для классов коллекций в
> библиотеке Java является интерфейс Collection. В его состав входят два
> основных метода:
>
> public interface Collection
> {
> boolean add(E element);
> Iterator iterator(); }
>
> В дополнение к ним имеется еще несколько методов, обсуждаемых далее в
> этой главе. Метод add () добавляет элемент в коллекцию. Он возвращает
> логическое значе­ние true, если добавление элемента в действительности
> изменило коллекцию, а если коллекция осталась без изменения -
> логическое значение false. Так, если попытать­ся добавить объект в
> коллекцию, где такой объект уже имеется, вызов метода add ()не даст
> желаемого результата, **поскольку коллекция не допускает дублирование
> объектов**.А метод iterator() возвращает объект класса, реализующего
> интерфейс Iterator. Объект итератора можно выбрать для обращения ко
> всем элементам кол­ лекции по очереди. Подробнее итераторы обсуждаются
> в следующем разделе.

Comment: Collection - это интерфейс. Реализация может допускать дубликаты, а может и не допускать. Почитайте про это в документации, там же все написано.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Плохой перевод. Пeревoдчику захотелось употребить красивое слово "поскольку".

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add-E-

> Returns `false` *if this collection does not permit duplicates* and
> already contains the specified element.

Возвращает `false`, **если** эта коллекция не допускает дубликатов и уже содержит указанный элемент.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка перевода. В оригинале так:
**For example**, if you try to add an object to a **set** and the object is already present, the add request has no effect because sets reject duplicates.

Comment: про ошибку перевода написано в предыдущем ответе. что же нового добавил ваш ответ? уточните это, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте ответа, нажав [edit]

Comment: В том что я привел оригинальный текст, и там речь идет про конкретную коллекцию, что и спрашивал автор топика.